# WordPress Email Share button not opening in Outlook

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, share

I have a custom share button snippet in my single.php file. It works with other email applications, just not Microsoft Outlook. Any ideas?

```
<a class="btn btn-mail" href="mailto:?subject=<?php print(urlencode(the_title())); ?>&body=Check out this article: <?php print(urlencode(get_permalink())); ?>"> BUTTON HERE </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that , you missed to add the receiver email address.
The code should be

```
<a class="btn btn-mail" href="mailto:someone@example.com?subject=<?php print(urlencode(the_title())); ?>&body=Check out this article: <?php print(urlencode(get_permalink())); ?>"> BUTTON HERE </a>
```

Ttry this then let me know the result.